# Does directly visiting a url have the same effect as navigating via a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, path, routes

I have a voting system which records users' ip addresses, users can only vote once. If the array of votes contains the user's ip address, then the voting link will not be displayed to the user:

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if !ip_array.include? request.remote_ip %>
  <%= link_to "Vote!", vote_user_path(@user) %>
<% else %>
  You've already voted!
<% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def vote
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.votes = @user.votes + 1
  @user.save
end
```

But couldn't a user just directly go to `www.my_website.com/users/:id/vote` to bypass this? If so, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you prevent it is by placing the validation inside the controller action, rather than in (or in addition to) the view.

```
before_action :ensure_not_voted

def vote
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.votes = @user.votes + 1
  @user.save
end

protected

def ensure_not_voted
  # perform the check and stop on failure
  # already_voted is a fake function, replace it with your real check
  if already_voted
    halt(403)
  end
end
```

Comment: Where would I define already_voted? I don't have a model for actual users of the website; my User model refers to something else.

Comment: You need to move the `if !ip_array.include? request.remote_ip` logic into the controller. I have no idea how the real code looks like, there is not enough context in your code to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

For simpler solution, you can add a session token to each user, and check if the ip contains the specific token, like

add a `before_filter :auth, :only => [:vote]`

```
def vote
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.votes = @user.votes + 1
  @user.save
  session[:token] = request.remote_ip
end


private

  def auth
        @ip = session[:token].to_s

        if @ip != nil
            redirect_to :back
            flash[:notice] = "You have already voted"
            return false
        else
            return true
        end
  end
```

the user can remove cookies to vote again(few people can), for that case you can save the ip in the db and check against it